# How can i add empty constructor to RecyclerView Adapter android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I need to add empty constructor to my Adapter, but i have already primary constructor.

My code:

```
class RvStatesAdapter(private var stateList: List<State>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RvStatesAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

inner class MyViewHolder(val binding: RvStateListBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    return MyViewHolder(RvStateListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return stateList.size
}
```

I have tried to use `costructor(): this()` but in this case i dont understand what i need to put in `this()` brackets

Comment: `costructor(): this(emptyList())` ? or `class RvStatesAdapter(private var stateList: List<State> = emptyList())`

Comment: if you have a primary constructor (declared right after class name) all secondary constructors (declared in body) need to call through to it, hence the `: this(List<State>)` requirement.

Comment: Please specify the reason for wanting to have a secomdary constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can make Adapter constructor without params by instead of passing list in primary constructor use function to submit list in adapter.

```
class RvStatesAdapter(): RecyclerView.Adapter<RvStatesAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private val stateList: ArrayList<State> = ArrayList<State>()

    /**
     *  submit list to recycler view adapter for populating items
     */
    fun submitList(list: List<State>) {
        stateList.addAll(list)
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(val binding: RvStateListBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder(
            RvStateListBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return stateList.size
    }

}
```

Submit list using adapter instance

```
val list = emptyList<State>()
val rvStatesAdapter = RvStatesAdapter()
// init recyclerview properties
rvStatesAdapter.submitList(list)
```